# Objective c get parameter values from reposnse

Tags: ios, objective-c, response

My response :

```
data = {
"user_id" = "1";
username = "dame";
},
messsage = "success";
response = 1;
```

My code :

```
     NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:responseobject];
        NSDictionary *data = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:dict];

        int success = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict [@"response"]]intValue];
        NSString*userid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data [@"user_id"]];

 NSLog(@"%@", userid);
```

my user id is i am getting as null. I dont know what the issue.please help me out.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts first extract data from Api response  and then try to extract userid then it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the parent key

```
NSString*userid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data ["data"] [@"user_id"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
NSString *userid = [data valueForKeyPath:@"data.user_id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

**your data dictionary have entire responseObject  because you didn't pass dict["data"], change that line to get userId**

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:responseobject];
```

To get data you have to add **data** key

```
NSDictionary *data = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:dict["data"]]; 
int success = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict [@"response"]]intValue];
NSLog(@"%d", success);
NSString*userid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data [@"user_id"]];
NSLog(@"%@", userid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString*userid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[data valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"user_id"]];
NSLog(@"%@", userid);
```